# Telegram Bot Event When Users Join To Channel

Tags: bots, telegram

After create telegram bot, access and admin this bot to channel. how to get channel members list or event when users join to this channel?

Answer (score 28):

Pretty disappointed with the current answers, so I'll leave an updated (as of February 2018) answer that explains how to do this with the [Telegram API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) itself, as well as with the framework I am using, [Telegraf for Node](http://telegraf.js.org).

The Telegram API is both very powerful, and pretty simple as far as API's go. If you are using the polling method of getting updates, and not websockets which are a whole other issue, checking if someone new has been added to a group or channel is very easy.

The API method `getUpdates` returns an array of `Update` objects, which contain all of the possible information you could want including any messages sent, inline queries, and new chat members. To get any new chat members you simply need to access `update.message.new_chat_members` which will contain an array of new users. For reference you can look in the API documentation [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message).

To fetch the update objects in browser, or with curl, all you have to do is send a GET or POST request to https://api.telegram.org/botYOUR-BOT-TOKEN/getUpdates. Then just look for `messages->new_chat_members`.

If you are using the Telegraf bot framework with NodeJs you can use the `bot.on` method with the event `new_chat_members`.

Example:

```
bot.on('new_chat_members', (ctx) => console.log(ctx.message.new_chat_members))
```

I know this was asked a while ago, but I hope this helps other people searching.

Comment: @watzon the problem is that you get updates with **new_chat_members** only for groups and supergroups, but not for **channels**

Comment: Is there any way to get the usernames for the **new_chat_members**?

Comment: @t1maccapp is there any way to get updates for channels?

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько well you can't get them for channels, as mentioned above

Answer (score 4):

From [docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api):

> **new_chat_members** New members that were added to the **group** or **supergroup** and information about them (the bot itself may be one of these members)

So i think you can't.

Answer (score 2):

To get updates on users join **group** or **channel** you must correctly setup webhook for your bot. This update type is disabled by default. See https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setwebhook

> **allowed_updates**
>
> A JSON-serialized list of the update types you want your bot to
> receive. For example, specify [“message”, “edited_channel_post”,
> “callback_query”] to only receive updates of these types. See Update
> for a complete list of available update types. Specify an empty list
> to receive all update types **except chat_member (default)**. If not
> specified, the previous setting will be used.
>
> Please note that this parameter doesn't affect updates created before the call to the getUpdates, so unwanted updates may be received
> for a short period of time.

So, the request should look like this:

```
https://api.telegram.org/<BOT_TOKEN>/setWebhook?url=<WEBHOOK_URL>&allowed_updates=["chat_member"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a message about join a member to channel you need to create invite link with request to join, and when user go to this link your bot see it

Answer (score -3):

Yes! You can use this:

[https://api.telegram.org/bot[TOKEN]/promoteChatMember?chat_id=@[channelname]&user_id=[user_id]](https://api.telegram.org/bot%5BTOKEN%5D/promoteChatMember?chat_id=@%5Bchannelname%5D&user_id=%5Buser_id%5D)

if user is joined response is ok, else response is not ok.