# How to check if some user is subscribed to the channel? (not group)

Tags: node.js, rest, api, telegram, telegram-bot

I wonder if there is at least some way. I need to get information about any user, not the current one. The channel can be any. Most likely an authentication step is required.

One could try to get information through the bot about who subscribed / unsubscribed. But judging by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38324448/telegram-bot-event-when-users-join-to-channel/59617236#59617236), this only works for groups.

Perhaps there is a way to get a list of all channel subscribers?

For example, I need to work with [this channel](https://t.me/Edward_bil_trash_videos).

Thanks.